# How to handle different type of multi arrays columns values in json file through python

Tags: python

I would like to convert json file (with diffrent type of mutli arrays values) to csv using python.

Sample input json file:

```
    {
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 500,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "251476",
      "self": "hp://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/99999",
      "key": "SI-111",
      "fields": {
        "resolution": null,
        "lastViewed": null,
        "issuetype": {
          "self": "hp://jira.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
          "id": "5",
          "summary": "vi",
          "customfield_12607": "2018-01-21T03:30:00.000-0800",
          "status": {
            "self": "hp://jira.com/rest/api/2/status/10694",
            "description": "",
            "iconUrl": "hp://jira.com/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
            "name": "Incident Active",
            "id": "10694",
            "statusCategory": {
              "self": "hp://jira.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
              "id": 4,
              "key": "indeterminate",
              "colorName": "yellow",
              "name": "In Progress"
            }
          },
          "components": [
            {
              "self": "hp://jira.com/rest/api/2/component/1111",
              "id": "11111",
              "name": "TEST"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Incorrect output in CSV file:
[image]

Expected output in CSV:
[image]

Here is python so for json to csv converter:

```
import json
import csv


with open("/root/jira_input.json") as jsonfile:
    x = json.load(jsonfile)

f = csv.writer(open("jira_output.csv", "w+"))

# Write CSV Header, If you dont need that, remove this line
f.writerow(["key", "summary", "customfield_12607", "status","components1"])

for x in x['issues']:
    f.writerow([x.get("key"),
                x.get("fields", {}).get("summary"),
                x.get("fields", {}).get("customfield_12607"),
                x.get("fields", {}).get("status").get("name"),
                x.get("fields", {}).get("components").get("1").get("name")

])
```

You can notice that, it was able bring multi arrays column value "fields-status-name" fine but NOT fields-components-1-name.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of an example JSON file that exhibits the behavior?

Comment: @glibdud - just added json snippet in question.

Comment: Can't reproduce your output. With the information given (after adding a few close brackets to your sample JSON to make it valid) I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`. Presumably because your JSON doesn't have a `fields` key. Please test the data you provide before committing it.

Comment: @glibdud - json is validated now. Sorry as it was not formatted well before.

Comment: What your code is asking for still doesn't match what's in the JSON. You haven't accounted for the `issuetype` key. Please get to the point where you can actually run the given code against the given JSON to produce the issue you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to index a list using a string, when you need to use an integer.  And also assuming that the first item in the list is number 1, when in python (and many other programming languages), the first item in a list (array) is index 0.

So:

```
x.get("fields", {}).get("components").get("1").get("name")
```

Should be:

```
x.get("fields", {}).get("components")[0].get("name")
```

Also, if sometimes components may not have any entries, you'll get an Exception when you try to access the non-existent component.  So you'll need to check for that if it could happen.  The most straightforward way to do that would be:

```
components = x.get("fields"{}).get("components")
component = components[0] if components else None # <- whatever default you want
```